# Send Mouse event to QML object

Tags: mouse, qml

I need to send a Mouse event to a QML object, from QML. For example,

```
Rectangle
{
  id: rect
  MouseArea
  {
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: console.log(mouse.x + ', ' + mouse.y)
  }

  Rectangle
  {
    x: 0; y: 0; width: 50; height: 50
    color: 'red'
    onClicked: rect.click(randomX(), randomY())  // <---- HERE
  }
}
```

I'd like the line marked "HERE" to cause a click event for `rect` which would be passed down to the `MouseArea`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be some relation between your question and [this question](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/qt-qml/2011-January/002092.html)

Please take a look.

```
import QtQuick 1.0

Rectangle {
       width: 360
       height: 360

       MouseArea {
               anchors {fill: parent; margins: 40}
               onClicked: console.log("hello from below");
       }

       MouseArea {
               id: mouseArea
               anchors.fill: parent

               onClicked: {
                       console.log("hello from top")
                       forwardEvent(mouse, "clicked");
               }

               function forwardEvent(event, eventType) {
                       mouseArea.visible = false
                       var item = parent.childAt(event.x, event.y)
                       mouseArea.visible = true
                       if (item && item != mouseArea && typeof(item[eventType]) == "function") {
                               item[eventType](event);
                       }
               }
       }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `childAt()` function is the right solution for my case. Thanks!

Comment: The link is dead. Maybe add some info?

Comment: How do I send an event-click to the TextArea component so that it receives focus and places the cursor in the place corresponding to the click location? The method shown above does not work, because typeof (idArea [eventType]): undefined for TextArea.